# What are the potential benefits of using ferrite rings on the stepper motor wires regarding performance or accuracy?

Tags: electronics, stepper

I understand that [ferrite rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_bead) effectively reduce [electromagnetic interference (EMI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference). However, I'm not sure how much stepper motors are exposed to EMI and, therefore, if adding ferrite rings to the stepper motor wires has any effect. I'm curious how the potential reduction in EMI might impact the accuracy, performance, and stability of stepper motors in a 3D printer.